# How to sum up one record per day for one month?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I’m trying to do to sum up values in a month, but i only want to sum 1 entry per day for 1 month, i tried to use $limit before the group but only get 1 entry return.

Thanks.

```
[
    { 
        $match: 
        {  
            "fPort": 60,
            "rxInfo.time":   
                {  
                    "$gte": "2020-12-01T00:00:00.000000Z",  
                    "$lte": "2020-12-31T59:59:59.935Z"
                }
        }
    },
    { $limit: '1' }, ///// This only returns 1 record and not 1 per day.
    { 
        $group: 
            {  
                _id: "9cd9cb00000124c1",
                "Total":   
                    {
                        "$sum": "$object.TotalDaily"  
                    }
            }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed with the following query.

```
[
    { 
        $match: 
                {  
                    "fPort": 60,
                    "rxInfo.time":
                                    {
                                        "$gte": "2020-12-01T00:00:00.000000Z",
                                        "$lte": "2020-12-31T59:59:59.99"      
                                    }
                } 
    }, 
    { 
        $project:
                {   
                    _id:1,
                    year:
                            {
                                $year:  
                                        { 
                                            $dateFromString: 
                                                            {
                                                                dateString: 
                                                                            {"$arrayElemAt": [ "$rxInfo.time", 0 ] }
                                                            }
                                        }
                            },
                    month:
                            {
                                $month: 
                                        {
                                            $dateFromString: 
                                                            { 
                                                                dateString: 
                                                                            {"$arrayElemAt": [ "$rxInfo.time", 0 ] }
                                                            }
                                        }
                            },
                    day:
                            {
                                $dayOfMonth: 
                                        {
                                            $dateFromString: 
                                                            { 
                                                                dateString: 
                                                                            {"$arrayElemAt": [ "$rxInfo.time", 0 ] }
                                                            }
                                        }
                            },
                    sum : "$object.TotalDaily"
                } 
    }, 
    { 
        $group:{ _id:{year:"$year",month:"$month",day:"$day"},TotalPerDay:{$sum:"$sum"}}
    }, 
    { 
        $group: { _id: "9cd9cb00000124c1","MonthlyTotal":{"$sum": "$TotalPerDay"},
                }
    }
]
```